# Copy a BST excluding unique values

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
int table::copy(node*& newTree, node* oldTree)
{
if(!oldTree)
{
   return 0;
}
if(oldTree->data != 15)
{
   node* newNode = new node;
   newNode->data = oldTree->data;
   copy(newTree->left, oldTree->left);
   copy(newTree->right, oldTree->right);
}
else
{
   copy(newTree, oldTree->left);
   copy(newTree, oldTree->right);
}
}
```

This function works when a node containing the value 15 is a leaf node, (has no childern), however, if this node is a parent, it does not work. Could someone help me adjust the pointers so that it will create a new tree without 15 even when the node is a parent?

Comment: Did you not ask this question earlier?

Comment: I did not ask earlier

Comment: @Sailanarmo This one is subtly different framed around the same code. Steven please define "works" and "does not work" in terms of what you expect vs what you get. Often just doing that kicks the solution loose. Also consider drawing some pictures of what you want  to happen step by step and compare the drawings to what the code does.

Comment: @StevenSchulze that comment [is rather disingenuous.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691848/copy-bst-excluding-data) This is only marginally better presented than its predicessor.

Comment: What is the purpose of `newNode`? You create it, copy the old node's data, and then abandon it. It never gets added to your new tree. Also, the way your code is structured, if the node's data is equal to 15, you eliminate that entire subtree.

Comment: I don't see how this code can do anything but leak memory.